# method to return different type object list with parameterised type as argument

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to create a method that could return a list of different type of data. The type argument is to identify which type of data need to be processed and returned getListedData(Class type). I also wrote a private method createList(Class type, List list, String flag) that could be used by all type data to create the list.

The code is doing what I am expecting, but as new to the Generics, I don't feel confident this is the best way to write. Could anyone give me some suggestions? Especially on using generic with LIst and the reflect constructor to create the object instance. (The reason I use it is to make the method reusable to all types). And I feel annoyed by the cast :(

Those different type classes have the same structured.

```
    public class TypeA {
        private String propOne;
        public TypeA(String propOne) {
            super();
            this.propOne = propOne;
        }
        public String getPropOne() {
            return propOne;
        }
        public void setPropOne(String propOne) {
            this.propOne = propOne;
        }           
    }

    public class TypeB {
        private String propOne;
        public TypeB(String propOne) {
            super();
            this.propOne = propOne;
        }
        public String getPropOne() {
            return propOne;
        }
        public void setPropOne(String propOne) {
            this.propOne = propOne;
        }
    }
```

There will be loads of same structured data types.

```
    public class Test {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public static void main(String arg[]) throws SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, NoSuchMethodException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException{
            Test test = new Test();
            List<TypeB> b = (List<TypeB>) test.getListedData(TypeB.class);
            List<TypeA> a = (List<TypeA>) test.getListedData(TypeA.class);
                            //similar repeate.....
        }

        public <T> List<T> getListedData(Class<T> type) throws SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalArgumentException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException{
            List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
            String flag = "";
            if(type.equals(TypeA.class)){
                flag = "A";
                createList(type, list, flag);
            }else{
                flag = "B";
                createList(type, list, flag);
            }
            return list;
        }

        private <T> void createList(Class<T> type, List<T> list, String flag)
                throws NoSuchMethodException, InstantiationException,
                IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
            for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
                Constructor<?> ctor = type.getConstructor(String.class);
                Object object = ctor.newInstance(new Object[] {String.valueOf(i)});
                list.add((T) object);
                //do something with flag... 
            }
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I would have `public <T> List<T> getListedData(Class<T> type)` as it removes the need for casting the return value.

Comment: The instanceOf method might be your answer:

Comment: You can also write `ctor.newInstance("" + i);`

Comment: what problem you are facing in above implementation

Answer (score 0):

Better avoid cases.
You could do as follows, or use a static member of the class via reflection too.

```
public <T> List<T> getListedData(Class<T> type) throws SecurityException, 
        NoSuchMethodException, IllegalArgumentException, InstantiationException,
        IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String flag = type.getSimpleName();
    createList(type, list, flag);
    return list;
}

private <T> void createList(Class<T> type, List<T> list, String flag)
        throws NoSuchMethodException, InstantiationException,
        IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        Constructor<?> ctor = type.getConstructor(String.class);
        Object object = ctor.newInstance(new Object[]{String.valueOf(i)});
        list.add((T) object);
        //do something with flag... 
    }
}
```